# MVC Validation & Drop down list nullable element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am close to finishing my first MVC web app ever and I am very grateful what it taught me but still I can't figure some minor things out.

1. Validation
   So inside my model I got this:

   ```
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
   [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
   public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
   ```

But the thing is kinda not a single annotation works right.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dS2D.jpg
It displays an error I didn't specify (looks better tho). But the main problem is it never checks if the field is empty or not (or has 5+ characters, even better).
I got jquery.validate.js, jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js and ClientValidationEnabled, UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled are both true. I can't figure out what am I missing here. Other types of fields do this too.
My controler actions look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveEmail(EmailModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int x = 0;
            string[] stringedIds = model.ParseIds.Split('/');

            model.Id = Int32.TryParse(stringedIds[0], out x) ? x : 0;
            model.Contact = Int32.TryParse(stringedIds[1], out x)? contactsManager.GetById(x) : null;

            model.EmailType = emailTypesManager.GetById(model.EmailType.Id);

            if (model.Contact != null)
            {
                EmailManager.Save(model);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Contact",new { @id = model.Contact.Id } );
    }
```

---

2. I got this dropdown for choosing a type of email. And it kinda needs to be nullable (you could select it but don't have to). I have no idea how to make this work. With the current data it works like a charm but its not nullable. I cant figure out how to add a new element to the list (on the first place in list) and make it 'null'.
   This is what fills it up:

   ```
   @{
       EmailTypes emailTypesManager = new EmailTypes();
       IEnumerable<EmailTypeModel> emailTypes = emailTypesManager.GetAll().Select(x => (EmailTypeModel)x);
   }
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EmailType.Id, new SelectList(emailTypes, "Id", "Name", Model.EmailType.Id), new { @class = "no-borders-drop" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmailType.Name)
   ```

I figured that changing to..

```
        @{
            EmailTypes emailTypesManager = new EmailTypes();
            IEnumerable<EmailTypeModel> emailTypes = emailTypesManager.GetAll().Select(x => (EmailTypeModel)x);
            var list = new SelectList(emailTypes, "Id", "Name", Model.EmailType.Id);
        }
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EmailType.Id, list,"None" , new { @class = "no-borders-drop" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmailType.Name)
```

..brings me a step closer.

Can anyone point me out?
Thank you (:

Update 1:
I just realised that I called jquery.validation before the jQuery itself. So that solved my problem. The validation works now but I would still like to know what kind of validation is the one on the picture if its not jquery.validation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dS2D.jpg

Comment: can you give full view code to understand..

Comment: For the first question, the input element should be type="text" to get work your model validations......

Comment: I just updated my question. The validation works now :D

Comment: The image is a HTML-5 validation error. And as a side note, `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmailType.Name)` makes no sense since your binding to `EmailType.Id`

Comment: Yeah, I removed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the following data annotation attribute above your property

`[Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]        [MinLength(5),ErrorMessage="User name can't be less than 5 characters"]
[MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage="User name can't be more than 20 characters")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }`

2. as per my understanding of your problem you can use the option label as following

`@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EmailType.Id, list,"this is optional label" , new { @class = "no-borders-drop" })`

if you select 1st option the value will be null.

To get the model state error place the following code below the `if(ModelState.Isvalid){}` code block

```
foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values) {
    foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors) {
        DoSomethingWith(error);
    }
}
```

place break point in for loop and here you can find out which validation rule you and missing.

the best way is to return model state error to view is  `return View(model);`

in your case you can do

```
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
    //model state is not valid
    return view(model);
        }
else
{
//your code here
}
```

Comment: Yeah I understand that but you see it does not even go to the controler when I select the "None" option.

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EmailType.Id, list,"None" , new { @class = "no-borders-drop" })

I even removed the ValidationMessageFor.

Comment: The thing is when I select the Email Type none the model does not pass the IsValid check in the controler.

Comment: what if you make email typeId null-able?

Comment: It is nullable in every layer.

Comment: I have updated my answer to get the validation error in view and controller please check and let me know

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write it here I just removed the ModelState of the model that was causing the error and it feels bad but its working. I just added ModelState.Remove("EmailType.Id"); before the check.

Comment: :) Good luck with that